# Changing column value in CSV file

Tags: bash, csv, awk

In csv file I have below columns and I try to change the second column's value with 
`awk -F ',' -v OFS=',' '$1 { $2=$2*2; print}' path/file.csv > output.csv`. 
But it returns zero and removes double quotations.

file.csv

```
"sku","0.47","supplierName"
"sku","3.14","supplierName"
"sku","3.56","supplierName"
"sku","4.20","supplierName"
```

output.csv

```
"sku",0,"supplierName"
"sku",0,"supplierName"
"sku",0,"supplierName"
"sku",0,"supplierName"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may specify more than one character in FS value.

```
$ awk -v FS="\",\"" -v OFS="\",\"" '{$2=$2*2}1' file
"sku","0.94","supplierName"
"sku","6.28","supplierName"
"sku","7.12","supplierName"
"sku","8.4","supplierName"
```

Try this if you want to round upto two decimal places.

```
$ awk -v FS="\",\"" -v OFS="\",\"" '{$2=sprintf("%.2f",$2*2)}1' file
"sku","0.94","supplierName"
"sku","6.28","supplierName"
"sku","7.12","supplierName"
"sku","8.40","supplierName"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you probably know how can result be rounded?

Comment: You are amazing... I do not have enough score to vote :(